# Beamer - Dresden theme: miniframes appeareance and frame number insertion

Tags: beamer, themes, mini-frames

I am writing a presentation in Beamer using the Dresden theme. From a [theme preview](http://deic.uab.es/~iblanes/beamer_gallery/individual/Dresden-default-default.html) I saw that white circles are supposed to appear on the top bar below the section titles of my presentation (to indicate the number of *slides* in each *frame*, I guess). The problem is that they do not appear when I compile my script. Do I have to specify a particular command in order to obtain that?

Moreover, how do I add numbering of the slide progression (with respect to the total amount of slides in the presentation)? For instance, say that I want them to appear in the lower right corner of each slide.

Comment: That works only if you have some `frame`s inside some `subsection`s inside some `section`s.

Comment: I see, so is there some way to visualize the number of the slide (maybe with respect to the total number of slides in the presentation) with this theme?

Comment: Yes of course.. if you edit your question specifying this part as well as the position in which the frame number should appear, I will be happy to post an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Dreden theme uses as outer theme `miniframes` specifying that the footline is of type `authorinstitutetitle`

```
\useoutertheme[footline=authorinstitutetitle]{miniframes}
```

Thus, to insert the frame number (command `\insertframenumber`) with respect to the total frame number (command `\inserttotalframenumber`) we should take into account how the `authorinstitutetitle` is defined:

```
\def\beamer@theme@footline@authorinstitutetitle{
  \defbeamertemplate*{footline}{miniframes theme}
  {%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{upper separation line foot}
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,%
      leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{author in head/foot}%
      \leavevmode{\usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor}%
      \hfill%
      {\usebeamerfont{institute in head/foot}\usebeamercolor[fg]{institute in head/foot}\insertshortinstitute}%
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,%
      leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{title in head/foot}%
      {\usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle}%
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{lower separation line foot}
    \end{beamercolorbox}
  }
}
```

Now, in the lower right corner there's nothing thus it is possible to exploit the space in:

```
\begin{beamercolorbox}[ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,%
   leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{title in head/foot}%
   {\usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle}%
 \end{beamercolorbox}%
```

by adding:

```
\begin{beamercolorbox}[ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,%
      leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{title in head/foot}%
      {\usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle}%
      \hfill%
      {\usebeamerfont{frame number}\usebeamercolor[fg]{frame number}\insertframenumber~\frameofframes~\inserttotalframenumber}
```

Notice that as separator between the frame numbers there's a command: `\frameofframes`. It is defined as:

```
\newcommand{\frameofframes}{/}
\newcommand{\setframeofframes}[1]{\renewcommand{\frameofframes}{#1}}
```

This allows you to modify the standard representation (`1/5` for example), with something else; for instance:

```
\setframeofframes{of}
```

will provide `1 of 5`.

The code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usetheme{Dresden}

\author{My name}
\title{My presentation}
\institute{My institute}

\newcommand{\frameofframes}{/}
\newcommand{\setframeofframes}[1]{\renewcommand{\frameofframes}{#1}}

\setframeofframes{of}
\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{footline}
  {%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{upper separation line foot}
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,%
      leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{author in head/foot}%
      \leavevmode{\usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor}%
      \hfill%
      {\usebeamerfont{institute in head/foot}\usebeamercolor[fg]{institute in head/foot}\insertshortinstitute}%
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,%
      leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{title in head/foot}%
      {\usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle}%
      \hfill%
      {\usebeamerfont{frame number}\usebeamercolor[fg]{frame number}\insertframenumber~\frameofframes~\inserttotalframenumber}
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{lower separation line foot}
    \end{beamercolorbox}
  }
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{One}
\subsection{One-one}

\frame{\frametitle{X-one} bla bla bla}
\frame{\frametitle{X-one-a} bla bla bla}
\frame{\frametitle{X-one-b} bla bla bla}

\subsection{One-two}

\frame{\frametitle{X-one} bla bla bla}
\frame{\frametitle{X-one-a} bla bla bla}
\frame{\frametitle{X-one-b} bla bla bla}


\section{Two}
\subsection{Two-one}

\frame{\frametitle{X-one} bla bla bla}
\frame{\frametitle{X-one-a} bla bla bla}
\frame{\frametitle{X-one-b} bla bla bla}

\subsection{Two-two}

\frame{\frametitle{X-one} bla bla bla}
\frame{\frametitle{X-one-a} bla bla bla}
\frame{\frametitle{X-one-b} bla bla bla}

\section{Three}
\subsection{Three-one}

\frame{\frametitle{X-one} bla bla bla}
\frame{\frametitle{X-one-a} bla bla bla}
\frame{\frametitle{X-one-b} bla bla bla}

\subsection{Three-two}

\frame{\frametitle{X-one} bla bla bla}
\frame{\frametitle{X-one-a} bla bla bla}
\frame{\frametitle{X-one-b} bla bla bla}

\end{document}
```

One frame as result:

[image]