# Beamer Class, I want to use \footfullcite (i.e. i want author (year), "In:" journal, volume, pages) to create footnote citations + biblatex ordering

Tags: beamer, biblatex, footnotes

**MWE**:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}
%\UseRawInputEncoding

% Cannot enable in Xelatex
\usepackage{pgfpages}
% \setbeameroption{hide notes} % Only slides
% \setbeameroption{show only notes} % Only notes
% \setbeameroption{show notes on second screen}

% other packages
\usepackage{latexsym,amsmath,xcolor,multicol,booktabs,calligra}
\usepackage{graphicx,listings,stackengine}
\usepackage{lipsum} 
\usepackage{verbatim} 
\usepackage{csquotes} 
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools} 
\usepackage{amsfonts} 
\usepackage{braket} 
\usepackage{bm} 
\DeclareMathOperator\erfc{erfc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[hang, small,labelfont=bf,up,textfont=it,up]{caption} 
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage[rightcaption]{sidecap}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\graphicspath{{./Immagini/}} 
\renewcommand\captionfont{\footnotesize} 
\renewcommand\captionlabelfont{\bfseries}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{array} 
\usepackage{supertabular} 
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{rotating} 
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{url} 
\usepackage{gensymb}

%\usefonttheme{professionalfonts} % using non standard fonts for beamer
%\usefonttheme{serif} % default family is serif
%\usetheme{Warsaw} %per cambiare font mutare o meno questa opzione

%% Enable only in Xelatex
% \usepackage{pstricks}

\author[pluto]{mickey}
\title{thoughts}
\subtitle{}
\institute [ciao] {bao  \\miao}
\date{September 32, 2022}
\usepackage{QUT}

% defs
\def\cmd#1{\texttt{\color{red}\footnotesize $\backslash$#1}}
\def\env#1{\texttt{\color{blue}\footnotesize #1}}
\definecolor{deepblue}{rgb}{0,0,0.5}
\definecolor{deepred}{rgb}{0.6,0,0}
\definecolor{deepgreen}{rgb}{0,0.5,0}
\definecolor{halfgray}{gray}{0.55}

\lstset{
    basicstyle=\rmfamily\tiny,
    keywordstyle=\bfseries\color{deepblue},
    emphstyle=\rmfamily\color{deepred},    % Custom highlighting style
    stringstyle=\color{deepgreen},
    numbers=left,
    numberstyle=\small\color{halfgray},
    rulesepcolor=\color{red!20!green!20!blue!20},
    frame=shadowbox,
}

\usepackage[natbib=true,style=authoryear,backend=bibtex,useprefix=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bib.bib}
\setbeamerfont{footnote}{size=\tiny} %reduce the size of the footnote citation

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

    \begin{document}
    \section{section}

    \begin{frame}{first frame}
    
    \begin{itemize}
       
        \item hello~\footfullcite{Yu2011}.
    \end{itemize}

    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}{secondframe}
    \begin{figure}[H]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{}
        \caption{some frame with some picture..}
    \end{figure}
    
    \end{frame}

     \begin{frame}{third frame - back to the first frame, for example}
  
    \begin{itemize}
        \item hello~\footfullcite{Yu2011}.
        \item new citations..~\footfullcite{Szigeti_2012}.
    \end{itemize}

    \end{frame}

     \end{document}
```

**QUT.sty file**:

```
\mode<presentation>

\newif\ifbeamer@secheader
\beamer@secheaderfalse

%\DeclareOptionBeamer{secheader}{\beamer@secheadertrue}
\ProcessOptionsBeamer

\useoutertheme[footline=authorinstitutetitle,subsection=false]{smoothbars}
\makeatletter % [add curpage/total page at the bottom](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/100838/beamer-dresden-theme-miniframes-appeareance-and-frame-number-insertion)
\newcommand{\frameofframes}{/}
\newcommand{\setframeofframes}[1]{\renewcommand{\frameofframes}{#1}}
\setbeamertemplate{footline} 
  {%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=15pt]{upper separation line foot}
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,%
      leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{author in head/foot}%
      \leavevmode{\usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor}%
      \hfill%
      {\usebeamerfont{institute in head/foot}\usebeamercolor[fg]{institute in head/foot}\insertshortinstitute}%
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,%
      leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{title in head/foot}%
      {\usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle}%
      \hfill%
      {\usebeamerfont{frame number}\usebeamercolor[fg]{frame number}\insertframenumber~\frameofframes~\inserttotalframenumber}
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{lower separation line foot}
    \end{beamercolorbox}
  }
\makeatother

\useinnertheme{circles}

%\useoutertheme{default}
%\useinnertheme[shadow=true]{rounded}

%define qut theme color 
\xdefinecolor{qut}{HTML}{00407a}  %PANTONE 541 BLUE
\setbeamercolor{footline}{bg=qut}
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{bg=qut,fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{title}{bg=qut}
\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{size=\large}
%\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
%\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}[text]
\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]

\setbeamercolor{palette primary}{use=structure,fg=white,bg=structure.fg}
\setbeamercolor{palette secondary}{use=structure,fg=white,bg=structure.fg!75!black}
\setbeamercolor{palette tertiary}{use=structure,fg=white,bg=structure.fg!50!black}
\setbeamercolor{palette quaternary}{fg=white,bg=structure.fg!50!black}
%\setbeamercolor*{sidebar}{use=structure,bg=structure.fg}
\setbeamercolor{titlelike}{parent=palette primary}

%% try
\setbeamercolor{block title}{bg=qut}
\setbeamercolor*{block title example}{use={normal text,example text},bg=white,fg=qut}
\setbeamercolor{fine separation line}{}
\setbeamercolor{item projected}{fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{palette sidebar primary}{use=normal text,fg=normal text.fg}
\setbeamercolor{palette sidebar quaternary}{use=structure,fg=structure.fg}
\setbeamercolor{palette sidebar secondary}{use=structure,fg=structure.fg}
\setbeamercolor{palette sidebar tertiary}{use=normal text,fg=normal text.fg}
%\setbeamercolor{palette sidebar quaternary}{fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{section in sidebar}{fg=brown}
\setbeamercolor{section in sidebar shaded}{fg=grey}
\setbeamercolor{separation line}{}
\setbeamercolor{sidebar}{bg=qut}
\setbeamercolor{sidebar}{parent=palette primary}
\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=qut}
\setbeamercolor{subsection in sidebar}{fg=brown}
\setbeamercolor{subsection in sidebar shaded}{fg=grey}

\begin{comment}
\AtBeginSection[]{
    \begin{frame}
        \tableofcontents[sectionstyle=show/shaded,subsectionstyle=show/shaded/hide,subsubsectionstyle=show/shaded/hide]
    \end{frame}
}

\AtBeginSubsection[]{
    \begin{frame}
        \tableofcontents[sectionstyle=show/shaded,subsectionstyle=show/shaded/hide,subsubsectionstyle=show/shaded/hide]
    \end{frame}
}
\end{comment}

\mode
<all>
```

**bib.bib file**:

```
@Article{Yu2011,
    author={Yu, N. and Tinto, M.},
    @title={Gravitational wave detection with single-laser atom interferometers},
    journal={General Relativity and Gravitation},
    year={2011},
    volume={43},
    number={7},
    pages={1943-1952},
    @url = {https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10714-010-1055-8},
}

@article{Szigeti_2012,
    year = 2012,
    month = {Feb},
    publisher = {{IOP} Publishing},
    volume = {14},
    number = {2},
    pages = {023009},
    author = {S S Szigeti and J E Debs and J J Hope and N P Robins and J D Close},
    @title = {{Why momentum width matters for atom interferometry with Bragg pulses}},
    journal = {New Journal of Physics},
    @doi = {10.1088/1367-2630/14/2/023009},
    @url = {https://doi.org/10.1088/1367-2630/14/2/023009}
}
```

I'm using beamer class and I'd like to have citations to papers in my presentation as in picture:

[image]

i.e. I want to use \footfullcite (i.e. i want author (year), "In:" journal, volume, pages) to create footnote citations + biblatek ordering

The problem is: when I cite (using \footfullcite) a paper already cited, I'd like to have the same numbering in footnote.
For example in the third frame I cite Yu for the second time: I'd like the appeareance of the footnumber "1" instead of "2".

[image]

How do I do it?

**Most importantly**: I'd like to mantain the same layout of the citation (meaning: bold blu for author and year, blue for journal exc..)

Thank you very much.

Comment: A suggestion: stylistically, I don’t think it’s a good idea to repeat footnote numbering just because the footnote is the same.