# Accents characters are hidden in beamer mode

Tags: beamer, unicode, font-encodings

I am trying to use a beamer template that I a user shared with me. Unfortunately, I have an issue using accents (because I write in French) : It seems like characters using accents are ignored and not shown on the template. For instance writing :
"Etalement à interface élastique" gives "Etalement interface lastique"[image]

I use this sty file : named "YTU.sty"

```
    \mode<presentation>

\newif\ifbeamer@secheader
\beamer@secheaderfalse

%\DeclareOptionBeamer{secheader}{\beamer@secheadertrue}
\ProcessOptionsBeamer

\useoutertheme[footline=authorinstitutetitle,subsection=false]{smoothbars}
\makeatletter % [add curpage/total page at the bottom](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/100838/beamer-dresden-theme-miniframes-appeareance-and-frame-number-insertion)
\newcommand{\frameofframes}{/}
\newcommand{\setframeofframes}[1]{\renewcommand{\frameofframes}{#1}}
\setbeamertemplate{footline} 
  {%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{upper separation line foot}
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,%
      leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{author in head/foot}%
      \leavevmode{\usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor}%
      \hfill%
      {\usebeamerfont{institute in head/foot}\usebeamercolor[fg]{institute in head/foot}\insertshortinstitute}%
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,%
      leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{title in head/foot}%
      {\usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle}%
      \hfill%
      {\usebeamerfont{frame number}\usebeamercolor[fg]{frame number}\insertframenumber~\frameofframes~\inserttotalframenumber}
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{lower separation line foot}
    \end{beamercolorbox}
  }
\makeatother

\useinnertheme{circles}

%\useoutertheme{default}
%\useinnertheme[shadow=true]{rounded}

%define qut theme color 
\xdefinecolor{qut}{HTML}{00407a}  %PANTONE 541 BLUE
\setbeamercolor{footline}{bg=qut}
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{bg=qut,fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{title}{bg=qut}
\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{size=\large}
%\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}[text]
\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]

\setbeamercolor{palette primary}{use=structure,fg=white,bg=structure.fg}
\setbeamercolor{palette secondary}{use=structure,fg=white,bg=structure.fg!75!black}
\setbeamercolor{palette tertiary}{use=structure,fg=white,bg=structure.fg!50!black}
\setbeamercolor{palette quaternary}{fg=white,bg=structure.fg!50!black}
%\setbeamercolor*{sidebar}{use=structure,bg=structure.fg}
\setbeamercolor{titlelike}{parent=palette primary}

%% try
\setbeamercolor{block title}{bg=qut}
\setbeamercolor*{block title example}{use={normal text,example text},bg=white,fg=qut}
\setbeamercolor{fine separation line}{}
\setbeamercolor{item projected}{fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{palette sidebar primary}{use=normal text,fg=normal text.fg}
\setbeamercolor{palette sidebar quaternary}{use=structure,fg=structure.fg}
\setbeamercolor{palette sidebar secondary}{use=structure,fg=structure.fg}
\setbeamercolor{palette sidebar tertiary}{use=normal text,fg=normal text.fg}
%\setbeamercolor{palette sidebar quaternary}{fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{section in sidebar}{fg=brown}
\setbeamercolor{section in sidebar shaded}{fg=grey}
\setbeamercolor{separation line}{}
\setbeamercolor{sidebar}{bg=qut}
\setbeamercolor{sidebar}{parent=palette primary}
\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=qut}
\setbeamercolor{subsection in sidebar}{fg=brown}
\setbeamercolor{subsection in sidebar shaded}{fg=grey}
\AtBeginSection[]{
    \begin{frame}
        \tableofcontents[sectionstyle=show/shaded,subsectionstyle=show/shaded/hide,subsubsectionstyle=show/shaded/hide]
    \end{frame}
}
\AtBeginSubsection[]{
    \begin{frame}
        \tableofcontents[sectionstyle=show/shaded,subsectionstyle=show/shaded/hide,subsubsectionstyle=show/shaded/hide]
    \end{frame}
}

\mode
<all>
```

This is the code of the template :

```
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
\documentclass[french]{beamer}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\UseRawInputEncoding


\usepackage{pgfpages}
\usepackage{pgf, tikz, adjustbox}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                patterns.meta
                }

% other packages
\usepackage{latexsym,amsmath,xcolor,multicol,booktabs,calligra}
\usepackage{graphicx,listings,stackengine}

%% Enable only in Xelatex
% \usepackage{pstricks}

\author{XXX}
\title{Etalement d'une goutte à interface élastique}
\subtitle{Presentation}
\institute [Sorbonne Université - ESPCI, Paris] {Laboratoire PMMH \\PSL University}
\date{\today}

\usepackage{YTU}

% defs
\def\cmd#1{\texttt{\color{red}\footnotesize $\backslash$#1}}
\def\env#1{\texttt{\color{blue}\footnotesize #1}}
\definecolor{deepblue}{rgb}{0,0,0.5}
\definecolor{deepred}{rgb}{0.6,0,0}
\definecolor{deepgreen}{rgb}{0,0.5,0}
\definecolor{halfgray}{gray}{0.55}

\lstset{
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\small,
    keywordstyle=\bfseries\color{deepblue},
    emphstyle=\ttfamily\color{deepred},    % Custom highlighting style
    stringstyle=\color{deepgreen},
    numbers=left,
    numberstyle=\small\color{halfgray},
    rulesepcolor=\color{red!20!green!20!blue!20},
    frame=shadowbox,
}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \titlepage

    
    \begin{note}
        {Introduce your self}
    \end{note}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Could someone help me to solve this problem please ?

Thank you in advance,

Comment: What should be the purpose of `\UseRawInputEncoding`?

Comment: While testing the original template it was told to me that is used to display the code but to be honest I don't understand its use very well. Does it interfere with utf8 encoding ? I have tried to remove it and now it works well...

Comment: @egreg Thank you for your remark but do you know what is the reason behind this error ? Thanks

Comment: Unrelated to the problem, but your preamble could do with a clean up: lot's of unnecessary packages...

Answer (score 5):

Remove `\UseRawInputEncoding`, that's all.

If you look in the `.log` file, you will see

```
Missing character: There is no <C3> in font cmss8!
Missing character: There is no <A9> in font cmss8!
Missing character: There is no <C3> in font cmss8!
Missing character: There is no <A0> in font cmss8!
Missing character: There is no <C3> in font cmss8!
Missing character: There is no <A9> in font cmss8!
Missing character: There is no <C3> in font cmss12!
Missing character: There is no <A0> in font cmss12!
Missing character: There is no <C3> in font cmss12!
Missing character: There is no <A9> in font cmss12!
Missing character: There is no <C3> in font cmss8!
Missing character: There is no <A9> in font cmss8!
Missing character: There is no <C3> in font cmss8!
Missing character: There is no <A0> in font cmss8!
Missing character: There is no <C3> in font cmss8!
Missing character: There is no <A9> in font cmss8!
```

The *precise* purpose of `\UseRawInputEncoding` is to absorb the input byte by byte without assuming any encoding; since the main document font (Computer Modern Sans) has nothing in the 128–255 slots, that's what happens. With a different font you might get arbitrary rubbish.

Removing that wrong declaration yields

[image]

Since you're writing in French you should also reenable `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` and add `\usepackage{babel}`.

Isn't the correct French spelling “Étalement”? I don't think you should omit accents on uppercase letters.